# Windows Batch: replace semicolon with underscore in filename

Tags: batch-file, replace

I want to use ffmpeg via windows batch to convert .wav files and put them in a new directory. For each file, I want to do the command

```
ffmpeg -y -i H:\input\file_10;18;33.wav H:\output\file_10_18_33.wav
```

Notice that the ; in the old filename are replaced by _ in the new filename.

So I will have to do something like

```
for %f1 in (H:\input\*.wav) do ffmpeg -y -i %f H:\output\%f2
```

But meanwhile, %f2 should be the filename of %f1 with the semicolons replaced by underscores. How can I do this?

Comment: Just put the file name in double quotes: `-i "H:\input\file_10;18;33.wav"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
for %f in (H:\input\*.wav) do set f2=%f & ffmpeg -y -i %f %f2:;=_%
```

Good luck!

Comment: Almost. This will put the new files in the input folder. But it helps me a lot.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the variable "in place" edit and replace :

```
c:\>set f1="aaa;bbb;ccc"
c:\>set f2=%f1:;=_% #rem will replace all ; by _ in the %f1% var
C:\>echo %f2%
aaa_bbb_ccc
```